# Implementation of a DSL in Haskell

Tags: haskell

This is probably a very basic question.

I am working on a DSL that eventuyally would allow me to say:

```
import language.cwmwl
main = runCWMWL $ do
    eval ("isFib::", 1000, ?BOOL)
```

I have just started to work on the interpreter-function runCWMWL and I wonder whether it is possible to escape to real Haskell somehow (and how?) either inside or outside the do-block.

I thought of providing a defautl-wrapper for some required prelude functions (such as `print`) inside my interpreter but I wonder if there are more elegant ways to co-loacate a DSL and Haskell without falling back to being a normal library only.

Comment: I don't understand your code, but `?BOOL` doesn't seem to be Haskell?

Comment: @NiklasB It is part of what ideally should become a shallow(?) embedded DSL.

Comment: If `CWMWL` is a monad, then you just need to write an instance for [MonadIO](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html) class. It is up to you how to embed IO actions in your DSL and how to run them with `runCWMWL`.

Comment: @JFritsch: Yeah, but your code example is supposed to be Haskell, as I understand it, but it doesn't syntax check, no matter what language.cwmwl exports

Comment: @NiklasB. It does syntax check. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @JFritsch: Sorry, my bad, I just checked in GHCI :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look into QuasiQuoting from [Template Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Template_Haskell). You could be doing

```
import Language.CWMWL

main = runCWMWL [eval|
     ("isFib::", 1000, ?BOOL) |]
```

or

```
main = [run|("isFib::", 1000, ?BOOL) |]
```

or whatever suits you.